# How to get 10 points to post a question with links

Tags: support, reputation, hyperlinks, asking-questions

How can I get 10 points to post my question with URLs?  Stack Overflow stops me from posting my question with hyperlinks.

Comment: Can't you post your question without hyperlinks?

Answer (score 7):

There's a list of ways to gain reputation in the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq). For now, post the question without hyperlinks, or if they're important don't actually link them (e.g. leave off the http://) and another user will probably edit your question to make them links